# Add current year in redirect htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I try to write a Rewrite Rule which route from:

```
/abteilungen/einsatzabteilung/einsaetze.php
```

to

```
domain.de/abteilungen/einsatzabteilung/einsaetze/2016 (CURRENT_YEAR)
```

My .htaccess looks now like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /abteilungen/einsatzabteilung/einsaetze.php %{HTTP_HOST}/abteilungen/einsatzabteilung/einsaetze/
```

Is it possible that the year at the end of the target get the current year and how can i do this?

**Edit**

Full .htaccess throws 404 error:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/abteilungen/einsatzabteilung/einsaetze.php$ %{HTTP_HOST}/abteilungen/einsatzabteilung/einsaetze/%{TIME_YEAR} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)einsaetze/([0-9]{4})$ $1/abteilungen/einsatzabteilung/index\.php/$2
```

Comment: Do you also want to to remove `.php` in target? Won't it cause 404?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in apache exist variable TIME_YEAR

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /abteilungen/einsatzabteilung/einsaetze.php %{HTTP_HOST}/abteilungen/einsatzabteilung/einsaetze/%{TIME_YEAR}
```

try use RewriteRule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/abteilungen/einsatzabteilung/einsaetze.php$ %{HTTP_HOST}/abteilungen/einsatzabteilung/einsaetze/%{TIME_YEAR} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Gah.. you were seconds before me. Upvoted despite of that. :)

Comment: Can you see an Syntax error? i got an 500 State.. :(

Comment: @NikolaiEngel please look you apache2 error log for more information why you got 500 error.

Comment: Mod_rewrite variables such as `%{HTTP_HOST}` ,,, are not supported in `Redirect` directive.

Comment: @NikolaiEngel I edit my answer try use rewrite rule.

Comment: Thank you all for you help, but if i click the Link: http://test.local/abteilungen/einsatzabteilung/einsaetze.php I get a 404 error and no redirect 301 :/

Comment: try remove `^` this char, this char begin regexp or past var http_host for example `^%{HTTP_HOST}/abteilungen/` @NikolaiEngel

Comment: I try to find the bug in http://htaccess.mwl.be but can't find the right condition

Comment: It works now!! It was my fault.. my htaccess isnt located at the webroot. it is under /abteilungen/einsatzabteilung/